# NP 300 2.4 Nissan cranking but not starting. There is no power noticed on the distributor

Tags: nissan, cranks-wont-run

We replaced a spoiled ignition switch with it's own key, after rebuilding the truck does not start. There is no engine light on the despot.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure, but your Nissan may have a coded key associated with it. If you replaced the ignition/key, but didn't get the new key coded into the ECU, it may not tell the coil(s) to fire as a theft prevention measure.